# How can I share variables in a distributed architecture?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, shared-memory, distributed-computing, distributed

I want to find a way to share a variable between different processes. Furthermore, I want to put mutexes so that only 1 process is changing it at a time.

I believe the framework does not matter, but if it does, I am using rabbitMQ.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I'm a little light on my distributed computing knowledge, but the difference between multithreading and multiprocessing is SPECIFICALLY that you can't share memory. If you're doing this a lot, be aware that you're going to pay a hefty processing cost to do so, since every bit of data that needs to be shared has to be serialized on one side, then deserialized on the other.

Comment: Totally agreed unfortunately... If you wanna have a closer look at my problem: I am building a distributed web crawler and I HAVE TO share the visited urls list.

Comment: You probably don't. That sounds like a job that can use a manager-worker model. The manager should decide what needs to be crawled next and hand the task off to the workers, record their results (possibly to disk?) then message the manager back saying "Done with URL <xyz>". Manager then adds that to the visited list, and continues on.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are right, I'm going to change my architecture.